# PIVOT result set produced by a query immediately following after CTE

Tags: sql-server, subquery, pivot, common-table-expression

I have two tables and I got the desired result from CTE and immediately following after CTE query.

The only part I'm not sure about how to pivot the result set by [Lead_Created_Month] column. I probably need to wrap the result set into a sub-query and give it an alias, but not sure exactly how. This is my code that works well to produce the desired result set, but then this result set needs to be pivoted by the [Lead_Created_Month] column.

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
Create Table #TempSales
(
LeadID_fk int identity (1,1),
[dateCreated] datetime 
)

insert into #TempSales
values 
(NULL),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(NULL),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(NULL),
(getdate()),
('2016-05-24 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-03-24 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-03-22 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-03-21 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-04-24 14:17:41.330'),
(NULL);

Create Table #TempLead
(
LeadID int identity (1,1),
[dateCreated] datetime 
)

insert into #TempLead
values 
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
(getdate()),
('2016-05-24 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-03-24 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-03-22 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-03-21 14:17:41.330'),
('2016-04-24 14:17:41.330'),
(getdate());
Select * from #TempLead;
Select * from  #TempSales

;with cte
as 
(Select * from #TempLead)
select count(l.LeadID) as [count of Leads], count(s.LeadID_fk) as [count of Sales],
 Cast(datepart(mm,[l].[dateCreated]) as varchar(2))+'/'+
--Cast(datepart(dd,[dateCreated]) as varchar(3))+'/'+
Cast(datepart(yyyy,[l].[dateCreated]) as varchar(5)) as [Lead_Created_Month]
from cte as l
    left join #TempSales as s on s.LeadID_fk=l.LeadID 
    and s.[dateCreated] is not null
    group by Cast(datepart(mm,[l].[dateCreated]) as varchar(2))+'/'+
    Cast(datepart(yyyy,[l].[dateCreated]) as varchar(5))
```

The above query returns the following output:
[image: Current result sent]

The final result set should look like this:

[image: final result set]

As you can see my code is missing calculation of the Conversion percentage.

So I wrote this code to calculate it:

```
--,Cast((Select count([s].LeadID_fk) from #TempSales as s where [s].[dateCreated] is not null 
--/* group by Cast(datepart(mm,[s].[dateCreated]) as varchar(2)) +'/'+ Cast(datepart(yyyy,[s].[dateCreated]) as varchar(5)) */
-- ) / count([l].LeadID) *100 as nvarchar(10)) + '%' as Conversion
```

But this causes this warning message to appear in SSMS which is correct. It's just me is not aware of a better solution.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 > value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,> >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this if you want to use a pivot - and you would need to use dynamic sql if you don't want to hard code yyyymm.

```
;with    cte as
(
select   1 as srce,year(tl.dateCreated) *100 + month(tl.dateCreated) as yyyymm,count(*) as leadcount
from    #templead tl 
group   by year(tl.dateCreated) *100 + month(tl.dateCreated) 
union all
select   2 as srce,year(ts.dateCreated) *100 + month(ts.dateCreated) ,count(*) as leadcount
from     #tempsales ts 
group   by year(ts.dateCreated) *100 + month(ts.dateCreated) 
)
select   case   
            when t.srce = 1 then 'leads'
            when t.srce = 2 then 'sales'
            when t.srce = 3 then 'comversions'
          end as ' '
          ,t.[201603],t.[201604],t.[201605],t.[201606]
from
(
select   pvt.* from
(
select   1 srce,year(tl.dateCreated) *100 + month(tl.dateCreated) as yyyymm,1 as leadcount
from    #templead tl 
) s
pivot (sum(s.leadcount) for s.yyyymm in ([201603],[201604],[201605],[201606])) pvt 
union all
select   pvt.* from
(
select   2 srce,year(ts.dateCreated) *100 + month(ts.dateCreated) as yyyymm,1 as leadcount
from    #tempsales ts 
) s
pivot (sum(s.leadcount) for s.yyyymm in ([201603],[201604],[201605],[201606])) pvt 
union all
select * from
(
select  3 srce,c1.yyyymm,cast(cast(c2.leadcount as decimal (10,5)) / cast(c1.leadcount as decimal(10,5)) * 100 as int) as conversion
from    cte c1
join    cte c2 on c1.yyyymm = c2.yyyymm and c2.srce = 2
where   c1.srce = 1
) s
pivot (max(s.conversion) for s.yyyymm in ([201603],[201604],[201605],[201606])) pvt 
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a quetsion on how can I use cast or convert in the Conversion PIVOT output? This is the last two lines of your code above:                                                                                       pivot (max(s.conversion) for s.yyyymm in ([201603],[201604],[201605],[201606])) pvt 
) t;

Comment: You can add case statements such as     case 
   when t.srce = 3 then cast(t.[201603] as varchar(max)) + '%'
   else cast(t.[201603] as varchar(max))
   end  as [201603] in the select immediately after the cte definition